# Semigroup preserves differentiability

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, semigroup-of-operators, parabolic-pde

Consider a differential operator of the form

$$Af(x) = a(x) f''(x) + b(x) f'(x) $$

for smooth, bounded functions $a,b : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$.
Let $P_t = e^{A t}$ be the associated semigroup, so that for a bounded continuous function $f : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$, the function $P_t$ solves $\frac{d}{dt} P_t f(x) = A P_t f(x)$.

I would like to say that if $f$ is bounded and twice continuously differentiable, with bounded first and second derivatives, then $P_t f(x)$ is also twice continuously differentiable. Is there a simple proof or a reference for this fact?

Comment: First of all, $f$ is not just bounded here. It has to be in the domain of your operator $A$ and this domain consists here of twice differentiable functions. By definition of the generator, the domain of your semigroup is also that of the generator. This is related to the Koopman operator, the generator of Markov processes, or the infinitesimal generator of a semigroup (depending on the field).

Comment: @KBS "By definition of the generator, the domain of your semigroup is also that of the generator." This is not true.